# Saving PDF for sharing using iText with backwards compatibility

Tags: android, kotlin, io, itext, pdf-generation

A problem with saving a PDF file on Android has been bugging me for weeks, making every Google search I do result in a list of purple links.

I have attempted numerous approaches, but have only managed to save a PDF file using the built in PDF creator, which does not fulfill my purpose.

I have a number of questions that I seek an answer to, and hope some of you can help.

**Question 1: Where should you save a PDF file you intend to share and then delete immediately after?**

***Q1 a)*** Is a ContentResolver & ContentProvider required, or is this only when sharing a 'directory' between apps?

Intuitively it makes most sense for me to save the PDF in the internal cache directory, share it from there and then delete it.

**Question 2: What is the approach for storing files with backwards compatibility?**

From what I have read, different SDK levels require different approaches for file storage, being:

- <= SDK 28 uses traditional storage methods, which is (using File API)?
- <= SDK 29 you should request permission for legacy storage, if using external storage
- >= SDK 30 Android enforces scoped storage

Using SAF (Storage Access Framework) seems to be the [recommended way](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) to store documents like PDFs. However, I don't intend to display a file picker to the user, when they are simply generating and sharing a PDF.

I am encountering this very generic exception, which occurs when iText closes the output stream. Below are some code examples and their resulting errors.

***SDK 30 File API test***

```kotlin
fun createPdfInternalSDK30(context: Context) {
    val fileName = "test.pdf"

    //  MODE_PRIVATE creates in internal storage, right?
    val out = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    // out path: /data/user/0/dk.overlevelsesguiden.de10her/files/test.pdf

    try {
        val writer = PdfWriter(out)
        val pdf = PdfDocument(writer)
        
        Document(pdf, PageSize.A4, false).apply { 
            add(Paragraph("Test"))
            close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

***Error***

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.producer.ProducerBuilder.modifyProducer(ProducerBuilder.java:97)
        at com.itextpdf.kernel.actions.events.FlushPdfDocumentEvent.doAction(FlushPdfDocumentEvent.java:103)
        at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.EventManager.onEvent(EventManager.java:71)
        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:849)
        at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:117)
        at dk.overlevelsesguiden.de10her.business.PDFService.createPdfInternalSDK30(PDFService.kt:118)
    Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 12
        \$\{([^}]*)}
```

**SDK 29+ Scoped Storage test**

```kotlin
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun createPdfSharedSDK29plus(context: Context) {
        val pdfCollection = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "title")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
        }

        var uri: Uri? = null

        try {
            uri = context.contentResolver.insert(pdfCollection, contentValues) ?: throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record")
            val out = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)
            val writer = PdfWriter(out)
            val pdf = PdfDocument(writer)
            Document(pdf, PageSize.A4, false).apply {
                add(Paragraph("Test"))
                close()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            uri?.let { orphanUri ->
                context.contentResolver.delete(orphanUri, null, null)
            }
        }
    }
```

***Error***

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.producer.ProducerBuilder.modifyProducer(ProducerBuilder.java:97)
        at com.itextpdf.kernel.actions.events.FlushPdfDocumentEvent.doAction(FlushPdfDocumentEvent.java:103)
        at com.itextpdf.commons.actions.EventManager.onEvent(EventManager.java:71)
        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:849)
        at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:117)
        at dk.overlevelsesguiden.de10her.business.PDFService.finalTest(PDFService.kt:118)
    Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 12
        \$\{([^}]*)}
```

**Manifest permissions**

```
<!-- Without this folders will be inaccessible in Android-11 and above devices -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
<!-- Without this entry storage-permission entry will not be visible under app-info permissions list Android-10 and below -->
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
/>
```

Comment: `ntuitively it makes most sense for me to save the PDF in the internal cache directory, share it from there and then delete it.` Of course that is ok. Why talk any further?

Comment: `What is the approach for storing files with backwards compatibility?` I have no idea what you mean with backwards compatibility.

Comment: You have two questions. You should have made two posts.

Comment: The `PatternSyntaxException` appears to be an iText issue, while the JRE accepts this regular expression, it is rejected on Android.

Comment: @blackapps because I just needed clarification on best practices for storing PDfs in this context, however it was not the real issue - which is the PatternSyntaxException I'm getting. Backwards compatability meaning, ensuring a consistent file storage approach across different SDK levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You brought up a number of issues. This answer focuses on the actual errors you show.*

The actual errors you show both cause a

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 12
        \$\{([^}]*)}
```

during initialization of the iText class `ProducerBuilder`. It happens here:

```java
private static final String PATTERN_STRING = "\\$\\{([^}]*)}";
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_STRING);
```

Actually here regular expressions in JREs differ from those in Android. In plain Java the regular expression `\$\{([^}]*)}` is accepted, a `}` meant as a character needs *not* to be escaped if there was no unescaped opening `{` before. Android, on the other hand, requires it to be escaped even then.

A fix for this has been committed yesterday - https://github.com/itext/itext7/commit/32bf2552770866dce4516798e7b11f26631ae92f - the pattern string now is:

```java
private static final String PATTERN_STRING = "\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}";
```

Thus, in the next iText release (or in a really current SNAPSHOT) that very error won't occur anymore.

Comment: Oh, I never expected it to be a bug in the library - thought it was just sheer stupidity from my side. The app should go to production ASAP, do you have any suggestion for how I might deal with this problem until the next release by iText, if I don't want to rely on a snapshot?

Comment: Well, iText is open source. Thus, you could simply retrieve the sources of the newest release and backport only the fix from the yesterday commit. Also you could contact iText support and ask for such a backport.

Comment: I just managed to reroll to a prior working version (7.1.3), so I will just stick with this version until the next release. Thank you so much for your help, I can't count the hours I've spent figuring out this issue.